# What is the external mic/speaker pinout for the Yaesu FT-4XR / FT-65R / FT-25R / SSM-16B?

Tags: yaesu, audio-interface

These newer HTs seem to have a different pinout than the older Yaesu HTs. The older HTs used a single 3.5mm TRRS plug - these use a two-plug connector, with a 2.5mm jack and a 3.5mm jack, similar to the [Kenwood/Baofeng style](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1891/13122), but with the two plugs closer together.

What are the the different contacts on these two plugs, and how would you trigger PTT?

Comment: I did a reasonably-thorough web search and was unable to find a pinout diagram, although the information might still be out there somewhere on the web.  The easiest thing to do might be to contact Yaesu.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to be able to trigger the PTT properly using a transistor. It requires a high value resistor. I used a potentiometer to find the correct position.

[image: potentiometer with transistor]

Based on a feedback I had, I recommend this update (adding a resistor between the potentiometer   and the transistor) which is ensuring the collector to have always a resistance for the collector.

[image: potentiometer with transistor and new resistor]

I fully documented the way I found it [on my blog](https://www-f4iha-fr.translate.goog/2021/11/17/haute-resistance-dans-le-declenchement-electronique-du-ptt-dun-ft-4xe/?_x_tr_sl=fr&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=nui).

Comment: Salut Olivier, et bienvenue à ham.stackexchange.com!  Thank you for posting the fix for the PTT problem.  We discourage answers that are just links, because links die.  (The link was broken but I fixed it.)  I tried to edit your post to insert one of the schematics from your blog, but I got an error with the image.  I will try again tomorrow.  I hope you don't mind if I share the schematic.  Encore, bienvenue!

Comment: I will update later today my posts based on your feedback. I understand your feedback. Thanks for the warm welcome

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but may get you closer.

[This cable](https://store.mobilinkd.com/collections/tnc-cables/products/tnc-cable-for-yaesu-ft-25r-ft-65r) at Mobilinkd works on the FT-65R HT. They describe it as working with any radio that uses a uses a Motorola M1 style connector. You may be able to back into the information you want through that Motorola M1 lead.

I've actually had the same question myself, so I'll update this thread if I find more information.

Comment: Good find! Will accept the answer if I can confirm this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

ok. so here's what i have figured out. the large jack (3.5mm) has the external speaker output at the tip of the jack.the last ring is the ground,obviously for that audio output. Now, for the mic/ptt switch i have found this :connected a bare bone 2.5mm stereo mini jack at the other input. I connected the GND (last ring) with the tip of the jack through a 1K resistor (for safety of not shorting anything) and VOILA..the tranceiver light went to red and transmission begun! eureka! .now if you connect in series with the switch a typical mic from a mobile handsfree headset instead of the 1k resistor as load, (mine was ~960 ohm) you get it working. The yaesu ft-25 i tested has a 3.3V voltage acros the head of the jack and the Gnd.